# Find, in radians the general solution of cos 3x = sin 5x

Tags: trigonometry

I am studying maths as a hobby. I have come across this problem:

Find a general solution for the equation cos 3x = sin 5x

I have said, $\sin 5x = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - 5x)$

so

$\cos 3x = \sin 5x \implies 3x = 2n\pi\pm(\frac{\pi}{2} - 5x)$

When I add $(\frac{\pi}{2} - 5x)$ to $2n\pi$ I get the answer $x = \frac{\pi}{16}(4n +1)$, which the book says is correct.

But when I subtract I get a different answer to the book. My working is as follows:

$3x = 2n\pi - \frac{\pi}{2} + 5x$

$2x = \frac{\pi}{2} - 2n\pi$

$x = \frac{\pi}{4} - n\pi = \frac{\pi}{4}(1 - 4n)$

but my text book says the answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}(4n + 1)$

Is the book wrong?

Comment: It may help to look at a [graph of your functions](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw9yU0KgzAQQOG9pwiuEpn-WXRRyBWKexFJNdppoxMyA4WevrWLbt7ie42NgUS3wS230Sm5MK66KsTAXwZiff5KB3pXFhFBbTUm4zu9dAOCw5NtG_FQw3Ffdj_oJ0qLE_FpO6CutPoOMjUnHAOunm2-uAelHBxHP0ifnCDZE0w4M7691WUFqjbmA3zZNEs=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin 5x = \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}-5x)= \cos 3x $$

$$3x=\frac{\pi}{2}-5x+2k\pi$$

$$x=\frac{\pi}{16}+\frac{k\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{16}(1+4k)$$

or

$$3x=-(\frac{\pi}{2}-5x)+2k\pi$$

$$x=\frac{\pi}{4}-k\pi$$

$$x=\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi =\frac{\pi}{4}(1+4k)$$

where $k\in Z$

writing $-k\pi$ or $k\pi$ does not change the solution set. Because $-k$ is the opposite of $k$ in integers.

Comment: I'm not sure about the last sentence. I would have thought that because -k is the opposite of k then it must change the solution

Comment: I mean it will give the same solution set by writing $-k$ for $k$

Comment: Is that because cos -x is the same as cosx?

Comment: @Steblo : take $x= \frac{\pi}{4}(1-4k)$ for $k=1$, $x=-\frac {3pi}{4}$. Now take take $x= \frac{\pi}{4}(1+4k)$ for $k=-1$, $x=-\frac {3pi}{4}$.

Comment: @Steblo : $\cos(-x)= \cos x$. Because Cosine function is an even function and its graph is symmetric to the y-axis or it can be say different reasons.

Answer (score 2):

If you write $m$ in place of $n,$ you reached at $\dfrac{\pi(1-4m)}4$

We $$\dfrac{\pi(1-4m)}4=\dfrac{\pi(1+4n)}4\iff m=-n$$

In our case $m$ is any integer  $\iff n=-m$ also belong to the same infinite set of integers

In their case $n$ is so.

Answer (score 1):

No, the two are equivalent. In particular, if $m$ = $-n$, then $$\dfrac{\pi}{2}(1 - 4m) = \dfrac{\pi}{2}(4n + 1),$$
so all that's really happened is tha tyou've listed the solutions in a different order.